# Transfer data between large MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, data-migration

I'm looking to transfer some data from a multi-million row table into another table. The problems I'm facing are:

- I can't use data dumps, because I need a WHERE clause
- I can't do a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` because putting all those rows into a temp table crashes the server

So I'm basically thinking I should do a stored procedure or something similar, which takes 100 rows at a time and inserts them in the other table.

Any ideas of solutions/best practices in this matter?

Thanks,

Comment: how about write some external program for this unit task? updt: its within one server and one db?

Comment: You can try using [SQLyog](http://webyog.com/en/downloads.php). There is a 30 day trial version which you can download. 
SQLyog has a data sync wizard which will help you do exactly what you are trying to (without really writing any code as such).

Comment: mysqldump allows to use WHERE, have a look at --where option - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.hts.html

Comment: Devart, the link doesn't seem to work, but thanks for the tip, I'll find the docs page on my own.

Comment: Really, it was wrong link:( Anyway, this should work - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'backup.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM <tablename> WHERE <conditions> <Other Clause if required>
```

Then insert :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'backup.csv'
INTO TABLE <tablename>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1,field1,field2) etc
```

Comment: I'm giving it a try as we speak. And where would backup.csv be located by default?

Comment: Never mind, I found it in the folder that holds all the tables for the respective database.

Answer (score 0):

What is your update freq.?

If you not need to track updates, you can  just using limit. I wrote in the past function (VB.net) that wait until rows=0:

```
Function ExecCommandInParts(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal Updater As Func(Of Integer, Integer) = Nothing) As Integer
    Dim limit As Integer = 10000
    Dim count As Integer = limit
    While count = limit
        count = ExecCommandWithTimeout(sql & " limit " & limit)
        If Updater IsNot Nothing Then Updater(count)
    End While
End Function
```

SQL = sql query to run (INSERT ... SELECT, DELETE ...)
Updater = delegate to update caller object/user what is the status of the command...

ExecCommandWithTimeout = function for execute SQL, and wait 500 milisecond.

Tested in heavy  production server, works.